# How can I call InvalidateSurface method when canvas is inside an ItemTemplate?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I want to be able to update the image that is drawn on a SKCanvasView. The canvas is contained within a Telerik SlideView item template. Here's how I draw the image onto the canvas:

```
private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();
    float x = info.Width / 2 - _currentBitmap.Width / 2;
    float y = info.Height / 2 - _currentBitmap.Height / 2;

    if (sender is BindableObject bo)
    {
        if (bo.BindingContext is MyObjectType o)
        {
            string file = o.Id + ".jpg";
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                _currentBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(file);
                canvas.DrawBitmap(_currentBitmap, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to change the drawn image after other events are triggered. I understand that to refresh the SKCanvasView, I call the InvalidateSurface() method. This works in my onTouch event:

```
private void Canvas_OnTouch(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e == null) return;
    if (e.ActionType.Equals(SKTouchAction.Pressed))
    {
        if (sender is SKCanvasView canvas)
        {
            canvas.InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I also need to change the drawn image at other points in my code. How can I access SKCanvasView in the other methods so I can call InvalidateSurface()? The OnCanvasViewPaintSurface method only seems to expose the SKCanvas and not the SKCanvasView, so I can't set a class member to that and access it from other methods.

Comment: Have you tried to use reflection?

Comment: The answer was right in front of me all along. The sender object parameter in the OnTouch event is actually of type SKCanvasView, so I can set a class property to reference that.

Comment: Ok, please post your answer to close this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this one myself. The sender object parameter in the OnTouch event is actually of type SKCanvasView, so you can set a class property to reference that.

Comment: This is usually what I do as well. It may be a good idea to accept this answer.